# How to get node with relative attributes in xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Hi everyone i've 3 div like that:
div 1:

```
<div class="productbox-container first" style="float:left">
<div class="product">
<div class="product_image">
</div>
<div class="product_price">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

div 2:

```
<div class="productbox-container" style="float:left">
<div class="product">
<div class="product_image">
</div>
<div class="product_price">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

div 3:

```
<div class="productbox-container last" style="float:left">
<div class="product">
<div class="product_image">
</div>
<div class="product_price">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

every content in 3 div is same, the only difference is in the classname,nomal way i can get node with 3 htmlnodecolection like this :

```
 HtmlNodeCollection htmlNodeCollection = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='productbox-container first']");
 HtmlNodeCollection htmlNodeCollection2 = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='productbox-container']");
 HtmlNodeCollection htmlNodeCollection3 = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='productbox-container last']");
```

Have anyway to get all in 1 HtmlNodeCollection ? Some thing like :

```
 HtmlNodeCollection htmlNodeCollection3 = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='productbox-container'+*]");
```

using * like sql ? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use contains:

```
HtmlNodeCollection htmlNodeCollection3 = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class, 'productbox-container')]");
```

Or more reliable:

```
HtmlNodeCollection htmlNodeCollection3 = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' productbox-container ')]");
```